# Difference between filesystem BTRFS size with df, btrfs and baobab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, btrfs

Today my desktop gave me a notification that my /-filesystem was 'full'. So at first i did some cleanup of files, packages and old snapshots.

However, when i removed the previous i noticed with the tool `baobab` that i only have 50GB of space (see screenshot). My `df -alh` command give me the result that my size is 140G and the command `btrfs filesystem df /` gave me the result 125G. If i check the partition size with `cfdisk` i get the result that if have 139,7G (so say 140G) available, corresponding the df -alh command. However i don't understand why the btrfs and baobab give me different results.
[Screenshot difference size output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qywP.png)

--Edit--

```
$sudo  btrfs fi usage /
Overall:
    Device size:         139.70GiB
    Device allocated:        136.70GiB
    Device unallocated:        3.00GiB
    Device missing:          0.00B
    Used:            133.78GiB
    Free (estimated):          3.63GiB  (min: 2.13GiB)
    Data ratio:               1.00
    Metadata ratio:           2.00
    Global reserve:      308.56MiB  (used: 0.00B)

Data,single: Size:125.68GiB, Used:125.05GiB (99.50%)
   /dev/sda1     125.68GiB

Metadata,DUP: Size:5.50GiB, Used:4.37GiB (79.38%)
   /dev/sda1      11.00GiB

System,DUP: Size:8.00MiB, Used:16.00KiB (0.20%)
   /dev/sda1      16.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sda1       3.00GiB
```

```
$sudo btrfs fi du -s /
     Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
 138.88GiB    96.00KiB    46.30GiB  /
```

Comment: What do you get from `btrfs fi usage /` and `btrfs fi du -s /`?

Comment: Would still like to see results of the second command, as it can explain the numbers shown by Baobab.

Comment: @user1686: I added the results of ```btrfs fi du -s/```

Answer (score 7):

With BTRFS, it is possible to run out of space when writing an amount of data that is
much less than the reported free space.

This is because BTRFS starts every write in a freshly allocated chunk.
But as the chunksize is static, and files come in all sizes, much of the time a chunk
is incompletely filled. That creates “allocated but not used” space that is
the problem.

You may see the problem better using the command `btrfs fi usage`.
Divide the used-size by total-size to get the ratio of inefficient storage.

BTRFS has a tool to "rebalance" your filesystem, called `balance`.
Originally designed for balancing data stored across multiple drives, it is
also useful in single drive configurations though, to rebalance how data is stored
within the allocation.

By default, `balance` will rewrite all the data on the disk. This is probably
unnecessary. Chunks will be unevenly filled, but you can use the above-calculated
ratio to filter, using the `-d` parameter to only rebalance chunks that are less
than that ratio. That will leave any partially filled chunks which are more-filled
than the average.

If the ratio was `0.66`, use the following command:

```
sudo btrfs balance start -dusage=66 /
```

You can run the above command in the background by appending `&` and check on its
status using:

```
sudo btrfs balance status -v /
```

Or continuously using:

```
while :; do sudo btrfs balance status -v / ; sleep 60; done
```

To see the difference, check out the final result using:

```
btrfs filesystem df /
```

For more details see the article
[BTRFS and Free Space - Emergency Response](https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2019/02/11/btrfs-out-of-space-emergency-response/).